# return a 2d array from toString() method

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm having trouble return a string 2d array so that it will display in table form.  Here's what i got:

if i write this code, it will display the array on one single line.

```
   public String toString() {
      return Arrays.deepToString(hidingPlaces);
   }
```

And if i write this, i get no output.

```
public String toString() {
  String aString = "";
  for(int row = 0; row < arrayName.length; row++) {
     for(int col = 0; col < arrayName[row].length; col++) {
        aString = " " + arrayName[row][col];
     }
  }
  return aString;
}
```

Last one, when i initialize the array (every box) to ' ' (a space), i get 0000 as output instead of [ ]. Oh this is a char array btw.  Please take a look at my problem.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're not concatenating the resultant string.

Comment: You say arrayName there, what do you mean by that, is the arrayName an attribute instantiated earlier? Also you are missing a += when you are updating the string in the for loop.

Comment: you have assign value to this again and again!`aString = " " + arrayName[row][col];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you meant

```
aString += " " + arrayName[row][col];
```

As it is, you're overwriting the string in each iteration.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int row = 0; row < arrayName.length; row++) {
     for(int col = 0; col < arrayName[row].length; col++) {
        aString += " " + arrayName[row][col];
     }
        aString += "\r\n";
  }
```

If you display it on the web form you could use `<br>` instead of `\r\n`.

Comment: @Impalerz try this: aString += "\n" + arrayName[row][col];

Answer (score 0):

Use a stringbuffer or a stringbuilder to concatenate your string object in the tostring method
Your aString gets initialized again and again without concatenation
Use stringbuffer.append here where aString should be a str in String buffer

Edit1

```
public String toString() {
  StringBuffer aString = new StringBuffer();
  for(int row = 0; row < arrayName.length; row++) {
     for(int col = 0; col < arrayName[row].length; col++) {
        aString.append(" " + arrayName[row][col]);
     }
  }
  return aString.toString();
}
```

Comment: i've never learned stringbuffer so i dont think i could do that.

Comment: Well its a straightforward concept.and there is always a first time. The reason you should use stringbuffer is because you are going to create objects unnecessarily in the heap since every string concat operation is creating a new object and it isnt a good practice to do so.    http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html